# Aligning text boxes with CSS pushes out labels

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align a section of text boxes but allowing labels in between them. Unfortunately they are being pushed aside. I'm sure it might be a css field type I'm unaware of that will handle this but maybe someone could help.

```
<div id="boxalign2">
            <p>
              <label>Contact Info</label><br>
              <label>Email:</label> <input type="text"/>
              <label>Office #:</label> <input type="text"/>
              <label>Other:</label> <input type="text"/>

              <label>Preferred method of contact</label>
                <select id = "myList">
                    <option value = "1">Email</option>
                    <option value = "2">Phone</option>
                </select>
            </p>
```

css

```
#boxalign2 p label{
display: inline-block;
float: left;
clear: left;
width: 100px;
text-align: right;
}
```

If the above doesn't show my problem, here is the whole:http://jsfiddle.net/HLLVt/

Comment: The "pushed aside" is because of the `float`.  Could you add a bit more information about the output you expect?

Comment: Do you want each pair of label+input on a different line as it's already the case in the first block?

Comment: Maybe my jsfiddle example will show it better. the 1st 4 text fields are aligned vertically. I'm trying to get these text boxes aligned horizontally on the same line with the label next to each box.

Comment: You really shouldn't be using `<p>` tags as wrappers...use `<div>` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you don't need the `float` property in your `#boxalign2 p label`, also you need to manage the width of the labels and the container depends of what you want.

Chek this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/HLLVt/4/

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `float` and `clear` styles and the `<p>` tags around each `label`/`input` pair and they will all line up on one line.  See http://jsfiddle.net/HLLVt/7/